# multiple list to dataframe usion python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dataframe, pivot

I wanna make dataframe using python

I have two multiple list

```
list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
list2 = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]]
```

I want to make dataframe like

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  3  4
1  5  6  7  8
```

how to code?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read the `DataFrame` docs? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas. Pandas is one of the most used Python libraries for working with dataframes.

The code would look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
        
list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
list2 = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]]
    
df = pd.DataFrame(list2, columns=list1)

print(df)
```